# Get values of a foreign key reference

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have two tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Director
(
   `DirectorNr` INTEGER NOT NULL,
   `First Name` VARCHAR (20),
   `Last Name` VARCHAR (30),
   `Age` INTEGER,
   `Movies` INTEGER,
   PRIMARY KEY(DirectorNr)
 );

CREATE TABLE Movies
(
   `MovieNr` INTEGER NOT NULL,
   `Title` VARCHAR (100),
   `Genre` VARCHAR (30),
   `USK` INTEGER,
   `Director` INTEGER NOT NULL,
   `Length` INTEGER,
   `Release` DATE,
   PRIMARY KEY (MovieNr),
   FOREIGN KEY (Director)
           REFERENCES Director (DirectorNr)
);

INSERT INTO Director 
VALUES (1, 'Peter', 'Jackson', 52, 17);

INSERT INTO Movies 
VALUES (1, 'The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey', 'Fantasy', 12, 1, 169, '2012/12/12');
```

how can i get the Director's name through the foreign key, with a SELECT?

Something like this:

```
SELECT `Director.First Name` `Director.Last Name` FROM Movies ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the `director` table and specify the relation in the `on` condition

```
SELECT m.title, d.`First Name`, d.`Last Name`
FROM Movies m
JOIN Director d ON m.Director = d.DirectorNr
```

Beware: With that design you can only have a single director for a movie.

And to escape table or column names use backticks only around the name of the element and not the combination of table and column

Wrong

```
`director.first name`
```

correct

```
director.`first name`
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT d.`First Name`, d.`Last Name` FROM Director d
WHERE DirectorNr IN (SELECT Director FROM Movies WHERE Director=value );
```

Comment: Get an error `#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row` if i replace `value` with '1'.

Comment: oh right sorry, the director might have more than movie, replace the = sign with in

Comment: Thanks this is also useful for me to get only the directors Name.

Answer (score -1):

Select m.Title , d.FirstName from Movies m, Director d where m.Director = d.DirectorNr

Comment: Please don't suggest the legacy implicit join syntax.